# Why does Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.censor not allow transforming the writer-type?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, parametric-polymorphism

[The signature](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html#v:censor) is

```
censor :: Monad m => (w -> w) -> WriterT w m a -> WriterT w m a
```

Yet we could easily have the strictly more general

```
censor :: Functor m => (w -> w') -> WriterT w m a -> WriterT w' m a
censor = mapWriterT . fmap . second
```

Granted, this would not work as easily with [the `mtl` pendant](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Strict.html#v:censor), but is that a compelling reason? Or has it perhaps something to do with performance?

Comment: I suspect _history_. `Applicative` wasn't a superclass of `Monad`, so one would have to write `(Functor m, Monad m) =>`. Also, the definition hasn't changed since version 0.3.: it still uses `do` notation. Ross Paterson could shed more light on that.

Comment: I think it could still be done with `Monad m => (w -> w') -> WriterT w m a -> WriterT w' m a` since `fmap f ma = ma >>= \x -> return (f x)`

Comment: Looks like an oversight to me.  Interesting note, though: [the version that operates on `MonadWriter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Class.html#v:censor) cannot express a changing `w` type.